# Не работает .bat файл

Tags: python, telegram-bot, bat

Я начал делать тг ботов, и написал батник для его запуска, но что-то не работает
Сам батник:

```
@echo off

call %~dp0first_bot\venv\Scripts\activate

cd %~dp0first_bot
python bot_tg_1.py

set TOKEN = (токен убрал)


pause
```

При запуске выдаёт такую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю, что проблема в пути, но что бы я не пробовал это не помогает, тем более я делаю по гайду, а там сделано именно так как у меня
Помогите, пожалуйста, что не так?

Comment: Ну хорошо, а где сам bot_tg_1.py лежит, в какой директории?

Comment: C:\python\tg\first_bot\bot_tg_1.py путь до файла, если в батнике я пропишу такой путь, тоже работать не будет